# where is the executor log when I run spark in local mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am writing unit test for my pyspark application, and I am able to set everything up running correctly based on this answer: [Testing Spark with pytest - cannot run Spark in local mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40975360/testing-spark-with-pytest-cannot-run-spark-in-local-mode)

However, I struggled to locate the executor log, I used FIND to look for log4j-executor, work, etc, under my SPARK_HOME dir found nothing.

Where is the log default location and how can I configure it?